# Python issues with csv,xml and special characters

Tags: python, xml, csv, unicode

I'm currently trying to gather text data from a csv file, and convert it into readable XML, according to a pre-defined schema. My issues seems to stem from reading and writing Norwegian special characters (ø,æ,å), and not having an understanding of how to properly use unicode.

```
with open(inputfile, 'rb') as csvfile:
dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024))
csvfile.seek(0)
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect)
idflag=False
try:
    for row in reader:
        if idflag:
            #print row[0]
            toEBU(row,id_row)
            #idflag=False #for testing, limits iterations
        if row[0].lower()=='id':
            idflag=True
            id_row=row
```

This is the code for reading the .csv file. The toEbu function handles the XMl conversion:

```
def toEBU(row,id_row):
file_id=unicode(row[0],"utf-8")
file_source=unicode(row[2],"utf-8")
file_type=unicode(row[3],"utf-8")
file_name=unicode(row[4],"utf-8")
file_desc=unicode(row[5],"utf-8")
file_keys=unicode(row[9],"utf-8")
file_rights=unicode(row[10],"utf-8")
keywords = file_keys.split(',')
#print row[0],row[4]
#Remember to use .strip() to remove spaces before or after string

if file_name=='' or row[1]=='Nei':
    print 'Name Error'
    return


tree = ET.parse('EBUBase.xml')
EBUMain = tree.getroot()
EBUMain.tag= 'ebucore:ebuCoreMain'
coreMetaData = ET.Element('ebucore:coreMetaData')
EBUMain.append(coreMetaData)

indent(EBUMain)


tree = ET.ElementTree(EBUMain)
xmlfile='xml\\' +file_id.strip()+'.xml'

#xmlfile=xmlfile.encode('utf-8')
print xmlfile
try:
    tree.write(xmlfile, xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8', method="xml")
except IOError:
    print 'Invalid Filename'
```

The error that I get is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "extractor.py", line 121, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "extractor.py", line 106, in main
    toEBU(row,id_row)
  File "extractor.py", line 26, in toEBU
    file_name=unicode(row[4],"utf-8")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 9: invalid c
ontinuation byte
```

And the string in row[4] is "Bryllup på Terningen".

I've tried reading the data with a unicode csv parser, but that also appears to create errors. So I'm trying to convert the characters to unicode before writing to XML. Previously, I had issues when writing the same strings, and the code would fail at the tree.write(XX) portions.

Edit:
Added a sample from the csv file:

```
18.6.,,Leveranse,Ferdig redigert 30 min AV presentason,Visning,Formidling,Digital historie,Ingen planer,,,
,,Kontaktperson,Tittel,E-post,Telefon,,,,,
,,XXXX XXXXX XXXXX,XXXXXXXXXXX,XXXX@XXXXXX.XXXX.XXXX,XXXXXXXX,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,
Id,Arkiv,Kilde,Modalitet,"Parametre, Filnavn","Beskrivelse, fri tekst",Script,Dreiebok,Opptaksplan,Nøkkelord,Rettigheter
D5.1,Nei,E,Tekst,,Manus til videoforelesning (inneholder deler og bilder  som beskrives under),Historisk oversikt over fyr og fyrliv i Frøya og Hitra,,Etter avtale med MMS,"Fyr, fyrstasjon",
D5.2,Ja,E,Video,25 minutter??,Film fyrvokter,Inspeksjonstur på Slettringen,,Opptak gjort av «Frøya Film og bilde» v Petter Vågsvær 2011,Fyrvokter slettringen,??
D5.3,Ja,E,Tekst,Fyr i krig,Digital fortelling,"Krigshistorie på fyr, med fokus på fyr i Trlag",,,"Krig, luftangrep, terningen",
```

The first lines are ignored, and only the lines beginning with "D5.X" are sent to "toEBU".

Comment: Are you sure, the file you are reading is encoded using utf-8?

Comment: No, as mentioned, I really have no idea what I'm doing. It's a cvs document.

I sort of assumed that trying to convert everything to utf-8 would magically solve everything. As I thought utf-8 would support 'æøå'

Comment: Could you paste an example of a couple words containing non-ASCII characters exactly as they appear in the original CSV? For example by adding the output of `grep 'Bryllup' input.csv | hexdump -C`?

Comment: Could you give me a little sample of the csv file?

Comment: Added a sample, re-edited to remove contact information.

Comment: I don't get why this was downvoted without a comment as you posted information, samples and gave the code you tried.  encoding problems are tricky and difficult to communicate as encodings are happening when you post on a webpage or write to a file to pass along.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To boil it down, your file is likely encoded in 'iso8859-1'.  I can create a (smaller) version of your file with:

```
from codecs import EncodedFile
with EncodedFile(open('n.txt','wb'),'utf-8','iso8859-1') as f:
 f.write('Bryllup på Terningen')
```

the params for [EncodedFile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html) indicate that the original (in python) is 'utf-8' and the file is encoded with 'iso8859-1'.  Now if I read the file using 'iso8859-1' I'm ok but 'utf-8' will give your error:

```
>>> unicode(open('n.txt','rb').read(),'iso8859-1')
u'Bryllup p\xe5 Terningen'

>>> unicode(open('n.txt','rb').read(),'utf-8')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-2649b633aa10> in <module>()
----> 1 unicode(open('n.txt','rb').read(),'utf-8')

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 9: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Thank you!
Is there any form of accepted "best practice" for how to encode the strings in XML files? I'm wondering if I should bother converting to unicode, and just keep everything in the iso8859 format, or if I should write using utf-8.

Comment: I know this is a couple years old, but I just ran into a similar issue and wanted to note that I ended up converting everything to unicode rather than writing in utf-8.  Not sure if this will help future users or if it's even best practice, but it solved it for me.